# strip ( from link while stripping child

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

During the execution of a stylesheet, I have a node like this:

`<a href="-----"> text (<a href="---">other text</a>)</a>`

I strip the inner  with this template:

`<xsl:template match="a/a"/>`

Works like a charm.
But I also want the strip out the ( and ).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use templates on text nodes e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="a/text()[ends-with(., '(') and following-sibling::node()[1][self::a]]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length() - 1)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a/text()[starts-with(., ')') and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::a]]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Your solution set me on the trail of this, which also does the trick for me:

```
<xsl:template match="a/text()[ contains( . , '(') or contains(. , ')') ]">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(. , '[()]' , '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

strange btw., that 'contains' can't have a regexpr like 'replace'.

Comment: `contains` was introduced in XPath 1.0 which does not support regular expressions. XPath 2.0 has the `matches` function to use regular expressions if needed.